# Spring Cloud Config Server: GitLab credentials get exposed

Tags: spring-boot, gitlab, token, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config-server

I am new to using spring cloud config server. I have set up a server via Spring Initlzr as Spring Boot Maven project. I want to use a private repository on a self-hosted GitLab server.

### TL;DR

The configured GitLab repository uri containing the deploy token (credentials) is returned in any response. How can I prevent this? I do not want to use ssh keys.

### Environment

```
Component       Version
Spring Boot     2.4.0
Spring Cloud    2020.0.0-M5
GitLab CE       13.5.3
Java VM         openjdk 11
```

### Long Version

GitLab allows to read (pull) repositories with deploy or access tokens. I could not find any documents on explaining how to configure this in a spring cloud config server. According to the official documentation on spring.io, the server uses JGit to communicate with remote git repositories.

So I have looked up JGit documentation and found an explanation on how to use deploy tokens with GitLab. You specify a GitLab repository uri with basic http authentication and additionally specify a username and password separately.
https://www.codeaffine.com/2014/12/09/jgit-authentication/ (Authentication @ GitLab)

I adopted this for the spring cloud config server and it works, but the credentials configured in the GitLab repository uri are exposed as well when content is served. when I remove either the credentials in the uri or the username/password properties, the server fails to connect to the repository.

application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://<deploy-token-name>:<token>@gitlab.home.local/spring-cloud-config
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=<deploy-token-name>
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=<token>
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
server.port=8888
```

Reading properties for a service returns a response like this:
`GET https://cloud-config.home.local:8888/some-service/development`
Response:

```
{
  "name": "some-service",
  "profiles": [
    "development"
  ],
  "label": null,
  "version": "b87f905c28cc911b056c5ecf6aef6724bfbbbe58",
  "state": null,
  "propertySources": [
    {
      "name": "https://<deploy-token-name>:<token>@gitlab.home.local/spring-cloud-config.git/some-service/application-development.properties",
      "source": {
        "my.property": "Hello from development",
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "https://<deploy-token-name>:<token>@gitlab.home.local/spring-cloud-config.git/application.properties",
      "source": {
        "my.property": "Hello from default"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Best regards,
David

### Update

According to the GitLab documentation you can read repositories with a private access token too. See link: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#personalproject-access-tokens

I have created a private access token on the GitLab server and tried to configure it inside the spring cloud config server. When I add the `?private-token=<token>` parameter, the server won't start because JGit seems to append a path to the configured uri which leads to an invalid url.
`Caused by: org.apache.http.client.CircularRedirectException: Circular redirect to 'https://gitlab.home.local/spring-cloud-config.git?private_token=<token>/info/refs&service=git-upload-pack'`

I also tried to add the token as a header field in the application.properties. But the property seems to be ignored or at least not evaluated at this point.
`spring.cloud.config.headers.PRIVATE-TOKEN=<token>` or
`spring.cloud.config.headers.Authorization=Bearer <token>`

Comment: Why do you have credentials in the uri and user name and password fields?

Comment: It currently works only this way. If I remove the username and password fields the server gets an authentication error from GitLab. When I remove the credentials in the uri the same authentication error occurs.

Comment: Without username/password:
`Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://gitlab.home.local/spring-cloud-config.git: Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered`
Without credentials in repo uri:
`Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://gitlab.home.local/spring-cloud-config.git: authentication not supported`

Comment: will you file an issue to see about removing the credentials from the response?

Comment: I did today, but already got closed as duplicate. 
I also issued a feature request for supporting GitLab private access tokens.